# Set default value of an attribute to today's date in properties window

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

How to set the attribute's default value to current date in the property window. I tried using System.DateTime.Today. However, I am getting an error.

I don't want to set this default value dynamically or in code.

[image]

Comment: Do you have default value for this field in the database? If so, change StoreGeneratedPattern to Computed for this field. The setting is three properties above the one you show in the image.

Comment: I want my default value to be current date. I am using the model-first approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible from designer. You must create your own partial class for your entity and set the date in default constructor:

```
public partial class InvertoryCategory
{
    public InvertoryCategory()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess there's no way to do that via the properties window. I would like to ask why did EF do this? What's the logic behind this?

Comment: Simply designer support only constants and `Today` is not constant.